# Custom message error with apache2

Tags: apache2

I am currently running a web server using `Apache 2.4.10`.
I would like to know how I can make custom error page, using the *proper* way.

Please, note that several solutions are available online, but seem deprecated.

I noticed the configuration file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages.conf`. It informs me that the default messages were available in the directory `/usr/share/apache2/error/`.
It also tells me that in order to change the layout, I should add the line :

```
Alias /error/include/ "/your/include/path"
```

But it doesn't explain where/how.

Moreover, I tried to change these files, reload `apache2`, and get an error page, but the error messages didn't change

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to make custom error messages is by using `.htaccess`.

First off, make an `.htaccess` file in your site directory. The syntax is easy:

```
ErrorDocument code path
```

So for example, if you were to build a custom error page for the `404` message, you could use this line of code given the path for your `404` document is `404.html`.

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.html
```

Same way for errors like 500:

```
ErrorDocument 500 500.html
```